# while using expdp getting this error

Tags: datapump, expdp

```
[oracle@oracle197 ~]$ expdp CITI_MDR_DEV_3/CITI_MDR_DEV_3 DIRECTORY=CITIBKP DUMPFILE=CITI_MDR_DEV_3.dmp LOGFILE=CITI_MDR_DEV_3.log

Export: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Mar 16 15:43:35 2024
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

Warning: Oracle Data Pump operations are not typically needed when connected to the root or seed of a container database.

Starting "CITI_MDR_DEV_3"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_13":  CITI_MDR_DEV_3/******** DIRECTORY=CITIBKP DUMPFILE=CITI_MDR_DEV_3.dmp LOGFILE=CITI_MDR_DEV_3.log
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
ORA-39014: One or more workers have prematurely exited.
ORA-39029: worker 1 with process name "DW00" prematurely terminated
ORA-31671: Worker process DW00 had an unhandled exception.
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qosdExpStatRead: expcnt mismatch], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 2141
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 57576
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 57809
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 29962
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 3493
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 13736
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 2429
ORA-06512: at line 2

Job "CITI_MDR_DEV_3"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_13" stopped due to fatal error at Sat Mar 16 15:44:06 2024 elapsed 0 00:00:30
```